# Object property value gets overwritten when creating new property Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

Consider I add new property to an object. Property name is based on an HTML data attribute.

```
var obj = {};
init = function(elem){
      var getData = elem.serializeArray();
      var propName = elem.data().dataName;

      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            obj[propName] = getData;
      }
}
```

This code gets executed whenever I submit a form (I have multiple forms on a page). Every time I submit a new form, new object property gets created, but the existing object property value gets overwritten (say I submitted another form just before that) by submitted form data.

Why is this happening and how to prevent that?

Comment: Assuming `var obj = {}` is executed in global scope. Your assumption that "Every time I submit a new form, new object property gets created" is wrong.

Comment: If you're actually allowing the form to submit, then the page is getting refreshed and so you're getting a new `var obj = {}` every time that happens. If that's the case, search for how to keep data between page refreshes, and you'll find more info than you need.

Comment: Can you send your code?

Comment: Page is not refreshed, otherwise how else would I get property from previously submitted form. Event looks like this: `$siteForm.on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  init($(this));
});`

Comment: Are the values of `getData` and `propName` what you expect? Accessing `.data().dataName` would correlate to a `data-data-name="..."` attribute, which is a little unusual. Perhaps you want `.data().name` for `data-name="..."`?

Comment: So, what you want is to create a separate object for each form?

Comment: Yes, here's my [pen](http://codepen.io/nikitahl/pen/zqgjLL)